# Remove milliseconds from date time field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field 'login' that currently shows date time as '2019-04-26 10:20:23.050'

I wish to only show '2019-04-26 10:20'

I have solved this before but cannot find the extract. The closest I can find now is

```
convert(datetime, CONVERT(nchar(16),login,120),120)
```

But that only provides '2019-04-26 10:20:00.000' whereas I wish to strip the last 5 zeros.
Any ideas please?

Comment: You have to do this on the front end or convert the date to a string and concatenate the date portion plus the time portion(s) that you are interested in displaying.

Comment: "last 5 zeroes" would remove seconds as well as milliseconds. To remove milliseconds you can cast as `datetime2(0)` (if you are OK with rounding rather than truncation)

Comment: `CONVERT(nchar(16),login,120)` would suffice. If you want an exact display format, you have to use a character type -- using a `DATETIME` leaves you at the mercy of how the client chooses to display these values, and you cannot enforce that it should leave off seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove milliseconds, you can use smalldatetime: `cast(login as smalldatetime)`

To remove seconds as well, use datetime2(0): `cast(login as datetime2(0))`

Comment: Thanks Bish, cast(login as smalldatetime) did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get to a very specific format, sometimes you have to convert and use string. Normally, you would want to return the native format and let the client apply the display format. Using simple string manipulation :

```
 DECLARE @Login DATETIME ='01/01/2019 10:20:00.500'

 SELECT CAST(CAST(@Login AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR(50))+' '+
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,@Login) AS NVARCHAR(50))+':'+
        CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,@Login) AS NVARCHAR(50))
```